# How do I mock or verify a call to print, in Dart unit tests?

Tags: dart

In my Dart unit tests, how do I verify that print was called?

I'm writing sample code for tutorials, and I want to test it. Many samples using `print` for simplicity. I'd like my unit tests to verify that print is called with the right input.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Update: [ZoneSpecification](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.18.0/dart-async/ZoneSpecification-class.html) allows overriding the `print` function. By running code-under-test inside a custom zone you can capture calls to `print` function. For example, the following test redirects all print messages into an in-memory list `log`:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:test/test.dart';

var log = [];

main() {
  test('override print', overridePrint(() {
    print('hello world');
    expect(log, ['hello world']);
  }));
}

void Function() overridePrint(void testFn()) => () {
  var spec = new ZoneSpecification(
    print: (_, __, ___, String msg) {
      // Add to log instead of printing to stdout
      log.add(msg);
    }
  );
  return Zone.current.fork(specification: spec).run<void>(testFn);
};
```

Comment: Can you please add example code that shows overriding print ?

Comment: `Missing return type for 'overridePrint'.`, `Missing type arguments for generic method 'run<R>'.` and `The argument type 'dynamic' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'dynamic Function()'.dartargument_type_not_assignable` are errors I see just by copy pasting the code.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think unittest adds anything specific for this, but you can override any top-level function in the scope of your test and capture calls to a log, for example:

```dart
var printLog = [];
void print(String s) => printLog.add(s);

main() {
  test('print', () {
    myFuncUnderTest();
    expect(printLog.length, 2);
    expect(printLog[0], contains('hello'));
    // etc...
  });
}
```

Comment: Cool - I wasn't aware of that functionality - I thought you needed to alias `dart:core` to override core top-level functions.  This solution works well.

Comment: As soon as  I moved the myFuncUnderTest function into another library,  the normal print was called and the unit test failed.

Comment: This approach smells, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [prints](https://pub.dev/documentation/test_api/latest/expect/prints.html) Matcher:

```dart
import 'package:test/test.dart';

void main() {
  test(
    'test print',
    () {
      const text = "IWuUtfAiAN";
      expect(() => print(text), prints("$text\n"));
    },
  );
}
```