# Can I override a built-in function in dart core?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to change the implementation of a specific function in dart core, like print() for example and use it directly across my app, is that possible?

I know I can make another function and use it like:

```
myPrint(String s) => print('output: $s');
```

But I want to know if overriding print() is possible as a concept.

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Zone/print.html - the docs say: *"Prints the given line.

The global print function delegates to the current zone's print function which makes it possible to intercept printing."*

Answer (score 3):

use this instead to runApp()

```
void main() {
  overridePrint(MyApp());
}

void Function() overridePrint(void mainFn()) => () {
  var spec = new ZoneSpecification(
    print: (_, __, ___, String msg) {
      // Add to log instead of printing to stdout
      log.add(msg);
      print('output: $msg');

    }
  );
  return Zone.current.fork(specification: spec).runApp<void>(mainFn);
};
```

source code from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38709440